# Output order of elements in Python recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Could someone explain following results?
In first case output is: '5 4 3 2 1'
In second: '1 2 3 4 5'
I don't understand it because I thought it use stack with LIFO (last in — first out).
And result should be '1 2 3 4 5' regardless of position "print" function.
I used PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Community Edition).

```
def pr(n):
    if n >= 1:
        print(n)   # 1'st case
        pr(n - 1)
        # print(n)  # 2'nd case


a = int(input())
pr(a)
```

Comment: In the first case you are printing on your way down the call stack. In the second casse you are printing on the way back up.

Comment: It's very simple: in the 1st case, the value is printed BEFORE going deeper, so first 5 in the 1st call, 4 in the 2nd call... ; in the 2nd case, the value is printed AFTER going deeper, so it's actually printed when the script "goes up" from the recursion.

Comment: You can see step by step execution [here](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20pr%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28n%29%20%20%20%23%201'st%20case%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pr%28n%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20print%28n%29%20%20%23%202'nd%20case%0A%0A%0Aa%20%3D%20int%28input%28%29%29%0Apr%28a%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=14&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%225%22%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: It might be clearer if you do both cases at the same time. Output: '5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5'

Comment: Related: [python recursive function that prints from 0 to n?](/q/17127355/4518341)